# Closed under nonsingular limits is equivalent to smooth structure of a Lie group

Tags: matrices, manifolds, lie-groups

The characterisation of a matrix Lie group is the following: Suppose $(X_n)$ is a sequence of invertible matrices converging to some $X$ in a set $G$ and the determinant of  $X$ is nonzero, then $X$ is in $G$.

In the text I am currently reading on the subject, the author claims that this condition of being closed under nonsingular limits is equivalent to the smooth structure of a manifold.

I can't see this at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-trivial result in Lie theory. It follows from the following more general result:

> **Theorem (Closed Subgroup Theorem).** Let $H$ be a Lie group and $G$ a subgroup of $H$. If $G$ is closed in $H$, then $G$ is an embedded submanifold of $H$ (and hence a Lie subgroup).

For a proof, see for example Lee *Introduction to smooth manifolds*, Theorem 20.12. Or also the [Wikipedia page of that theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_subgroup_theorem).

The non-singular limit condition is precisely the statement that $G$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and hence a Lie group by the above theorem. Note that $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group since it is an open subset of the real vector space $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$ of all $n\times n$ matrices.